# How can I remove Nan from list Python/NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list that countain values, one of the values I got is 'nan'

```
countries= [nan, 'USA', 'UK', 'France']
```

I tried to remove it, but I everytime get an error

```
cleanedList = [x for x in countries if (math.isnan(x) == True)]
TypeError: a float is required
```

When I tried this one :

```
cleanedList = cities[np.logical_not(np.isnan(countries))]
cleanedList = cities[~np.isnan(countries)]

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: That looks like the string `"nan"`, not an actual NaN value.

Comment: yes, it is a string. *[x for x in countries if x != 'nan']*

Comment: `if condition == True` is unnecessary, you can always just do `if condition`.

Comment: No solution provided so far are not satisfying. I have the same problem. Basically, it does not work for strings. Therefore in your case `np.isnan('USA')` will send the same error message. If I find some solution I will upload it.

Comment: Using `math.isnan` like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70856602) is the pythonic way.

Answer (score 217):

The question has changed, so too has the answer:

Strings can't be tested using `math.isnan` as this expects a float argument. In your `countries` list, you have floats and strings.

In your case the following should suffice:

```
cleanedList = [x for x in countries if str(x) != 'nan']
```

---

## Old answer

In your `countries` list, the literal `'nan'` is a string not the Python float `nan` which is equivalent to:

```
float('NaN')
```

In your case the following should suffice:

```
cleanedList = [x for x in countries if x != 'nan']
```

Comment: Logically, what you say is true. But it didn't work out with me.

Comment: Then the problem is in another area, the array you gave is strings which `math.isnan` will naturall through errors with.

Comment: Yes ! when I print the output, I got this : [nan, 'USA', 'UK', 'France']

Comment: @user3001937 I've updated the answer based on the new information

Comment: why all of you say it's a string but not float nan? if so, shouldn't the output be `['nan', 'USA', 'UK', 'France']` ?

Comment: zhangxaochen: it is not a string, it is a float. Look carefully at the updated answer; Lego Stormtroopr's converting `x` to a string so you can compare it. `nan` always returns false for `==`, even when compared to `nan`, so that's the easiest way to compare it.

Comment: After using this, I need the list back again in ndarray. doing so takes huge memory (more than 8 GB - my MBP hangs!)

Comment: This is the most reliable way to filter out the entry of null among the other strings in a list. I tried using  `if is not pd.isnull(x)` it didn't filter out the nan value

Comment: for some reason I think cleanedList = countries[ [str(x) != 'nan' for x in countries] ]feels more Pythonic but this can be personal.

Answer (score 62):

Using your example where...

```
countries= [nan, 'USA', 'UK', 'France']
```

Since nan is not equal to nan (`nan != nan`) and `countries[0] = nan`, you should observe the following:

```
countries[0] == countries[0]
False
```

However,

```
countries[1] == countries[1]
True
countries[2] == countries[2]
True
countries[3] == countries[3]
True
```

Therefore, the following should work:

```
cleanedList = [x for x in countries if x == x]
```

Comment: This is the only answer that works when you have a float('nan') in a list of strings

Answer (score 24):

The problem comes from the fact that `np.isnan()` does not handle string values correctly. For example, if you do:

```
np.isnan("A")
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

However the pandas version `pd.isnull()` works for numeric and string values:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.isnull("A")
> False

pd.isnull(3)
> False

pd.isnull(np.nan)
> True

pd.isnull(None)
> True
```

Answer (score 17):

```
import numpy as np

mylist = [3, 4, 5, np.nan]
l = [x for x in mylist if ~np.isnan(x)]
```

This should remove all NaN. Of course, I assume that it is not a string here but actual NaN (`np.nan`).

Comment: This gives me error: TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: Why not simply: ```x[~ np.isnan(x)]``` ?
No list comprehension needed in numpy. Of course, I assume x is a numpy array.

Comment: I assumed x is not going to be a numpy array as the question suggested.

Comment: It will expect float. Won't work  on lists with strings @ZakKeirn

Answer (score 13):

I like to remove missing values from a list like this:

```
import pandas as pd
list_no_nan = [x for x in list_with_nan if pd.notnull(x)]
```

Answer (score 7):

use numpy [fancy indexing](http://scipy-lectures.github.io/intro/numpy/array_object.html#fancy-indexing):

```
In [29]: countries=np.asarray(countries)

In [30]: countries[countries!='nan']
Out[30]: 
array(['USA', 'UK', 'France'], 
      dtype='|S6')
```

Answer (score 6):

if you check for the element type

```
type(countries[1])
```

the result will be `<class float>`
so you can use the following code:

```
[i for i in countries if type(i) is not float]
```

Answer (score 5):

A way to directly remove the nan value is:

```
import numpy as np    
countries.remove(np.nan)
```

Comment: Keep in mind, that if the list contains more than one matching the specified value, only the first one is deleted by remove().

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it would include using *filter* like this:

```
countries = list(filter(lambda x: str(x) != 'nan', countries))
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a list of items of different types and you want to filter out NaN, you can do the following:

```
import math
lst = [1.1, 2, 'string', float('nan'), {'di':'ct'}, {'set'}, (3, 4), ['li', 5]]
filtered_lst = [x for x in lst if not (isinstance(x, float) and math.isnan(x))]
```

Output:

```
[1.1, 2, 'string', {'di': 'ct'}, {'set'}, (3, 4), ['li', 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your example `'nan'` is a string so instead of using `isnan()` just check for the string

like this:

```
cleanedList = [x for x in countries if x != 'nan']
```

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion most of the solutions suggested do not take into account performance. Loop for and list comprehension are not valid solutions if your list has many values.
The solution below is more efficient in terms of computational time and it doesn't assume your list has numbers or strings.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
list_var = [np.nan, 4, np.nan, 20,3, 'test']
df = pd.DataFrame({'list_values':list_var})
list_var2 = list(df['list_values'].dropna())
print("\n* list_var2 = {}".format(list_var2))
```

Answer (score 0):

exclude 0 from the range list

```
['ret'+str(x) for x in list(range(-120,241,5)) if (x!=0) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to solve, and strangely none of the suggested above worked (python 3.7.9):

but this one did:

```
df['colA'] = df['colA'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if not pd.isna(item)])
```

Answer (score -1):

I noticed that Pandas for example will return 'nan' for blank values. Since it's not a string you need to convert it to one in order to match it. For example:

```
ulist = df.column1.unique() #create a list from a column with Pandas which 
for loc in ulist:
    loc = str(loc)   #here 'nan' is converted to a string to compare with if
    if loc != 'nan':
        print(loc)
```

Answer (score -3):

```
import numpy as np
countries=[x for x in countries if x is not np.nan]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. SO is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. This is particularly important when answering old questions with existing answers (this question is nearly _9 years old_, and has 15 answers). Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked, and how it improves upon what is already here. See [answer].

Comment: Sorry, I picked the wrong reason in review queue audit, the suggested edit should be rejected as "clearly conflicts with author intent" instead. It's author's responsibility to make answer helpful, other people should write their own answers.