# Remove nans from lists in all columsn of a pandas dataframe (pythonic way)

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe full of lists (in many columns) and these have nans in them.

I need to eliminate the nans from each column leaving a correct list.

Example of a cell:

```
['tag_001', 'tag_07', nan, nan, nan]
```

How can I remove these nans in a pythonic way?

Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011777/how-can-i-remove-nan-from-list-python-numpy and you just need another for loop , or apply here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `math` lib has a function which checks for nan. Easily use the filter function to return a new list that does not have a nan inside of it.

```py
import math

filter(lambda n: not math.isnan(n), ['tag_001', 'tag_07', nan, nan, nan])
```