# filtering PANDAS dataframe : error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 2988

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

I am learning Pandas but still at a quite basic level.

I am runnning the following line to filer a dataframe based on a list (WOODProds):

```
df['Only wood1']=df['Products'].str.contains('|'.join(WOODprods),na=False)
```

I get this error which I read should be related to some escaping character, but I cannot figure this out.

**error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 2988**

If I filter with other lists (so not with WOODProds) it works, so I assume the problem is with this specific list - which I imported from an excel column with .tolist().

Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: The problem is with WOODprods so it would be useful to post an example of that string. Its at least 2988 characters long, so trimming it down would be nice.

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is problem some regex special value(s) in `WOODprods` list, so is necessary escpae values by `re.escape`:

```
import re
df['Only wood1']=df['Products'].str.contains('|'.join(re.escape(x) for x in WOODprods),na=False)
```

Comment: Follow up question: I am doing exactly the same passing other lists which have the very same format, but I get this error: 
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, float found  . 
Is this some problems with items in the list ?
Thanks again

Comment: @Blackchat83 I think yes, it seems some NaNs or Nones.

Comment: @Blackchat83 Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21011822/2901002)

Comment: It seems it was actually blank cells. Which I replaced with a placeholder. Not sure it is the best way to handle this, but seems working now :)