# Plotting a scatter plot from a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Consider:

```
House_prices = [10050, 42300, 50206, 105000, 22350]
Num_rooms = [4, 5, 6, 10, 12, 2]**
```

This is the code that I have tried:

```
x = df.House_prices
y = df.Num_rooms
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

I want to plot both `House_prices` and `Num_rooms` into a scatter plot.

But I got the error:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'House_prices'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove Nan from list Python/NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011777/how-can-i-remove-nan-from-list-python-numpy)

Comment: where did you use pandas?

Comment: try ```df = pd.DataFrame(House_prices)```, then use ```df.dropna```

Comment: I would double check, whether your ```nan``` is ```numpy.nan``` or rather just a string, which says ```"nan"```

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list is not a DataFrame: you must explicitely build the DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(House_prices, columns=['House_prices'])
```

From that point, you will be able to use all dataframes methods on df including `dropna`

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(House_prices, columns=['House_prices'])
df.dropna(axis=0, how='all', inplace=True)
print('Total number of data points in House_prices = ',np.count_nonzero(~np.isnan(House_prices)))
print(House_prices)

Comment: I have tried it

Comment: Total number of data points in House_prices =  5
[10050, 42300, 50206, nan, 105000, nan, 22350]

Comment: but there is still "nan" inside and i dont know how to remove it

Comment: @Samuel: In my tests, `dropna` removed the nan... Maybe you should ask a new question (editing this one will make all the answers incorrect) with the new details.

Answer (score 0):

You assign `House_prices` to `df`. `House_prices` is a list and list does not have a drop attribute.

Comment: How do I remove the np.nan?

Comment: how do you remove a certain element from a list?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157106/remove-all-occurrences-of-a-value-from-a-list

Answer (score 0):

Here house_prices is a list and lists doesn't have drop features.

In order to remove the np.nan values from a list, you may use the below logic:

```
New_list = [x for x in house_prices if x != "Np.nan"]
```

Comment: What do I put for "new_list" and the "x" values?