# How to extract finite values of a numpy array without using a loop

Tags: python, nan

I have a numpy array that contains nan and I want to extract only the finite values to get a subarray but without using a loop.

For example:

```
import numpy as np

z = np.array([2, 3, np.nan, 5])
```

And I would like to use an instruction such as:

```
z_cut = z[z != np.nan]
```

but this doesn't work as it is not possible to compare nan this way.

I could use a loop with instructions such as np.isnan or np.isfinite to get the subarray I want, but I was wondering if there was a more efficient way to do it ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove Nan from list Python/NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011777/how-can-i-remove-nan-from-list-python-numpy)

Comment: It is a bit different from my post as the "nan" in the post you shared is not actually NaN value but a string. The accepted answer is closer to what I expected but thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `~` operator and `np.isnan` function

```
In [23]: import numpy as np
    ...:
    ...: z = np.array([2, 3, np.nan, 5])

In [24]: z[~np.isnan(z)]
Out[24]: array([2., 3., 5.])

In [25]: z_cut = z[~np.isnan(z)]

In [26]: z_cut
Out[26]: array([2., 3., 5.])
```