# Remove nan from list if some of the elements are data-frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have below `list`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dat = pd.DataFrame({'name' : ['A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'val' : [1,2,1,2,4]})
List = [dat, np.nan, dat, np.nan, np.nan]
List
```

I want to retain only those elements where they are not `nan`.

There is a similar discussion in [How can I remove Nan from list Python/NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011777/how-can-i-remove-nan-from-list-python-numpy), but it is only applicable if all elements are scalar.

Is there any way to remove `nan` if some elements are matrix/dataframe?

Comment: I am getting this error `TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
[x for x in List if isinstance(x, pd.DataFrame)]
```

If you insist on filtering on filter out `nan` only, then remember that it is a float instance, so:

```
[x for x in List if not(isinstance(x, float) and np.isnan(x))]
```