# How to combine two columns if one is empty

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table:

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | NA |
| y | NA | 4 |
| z | 2 | NA |
| p | NA | 5 |
| t | 6 | 7 |

I want to create a new column D which should combine columns B and C if one of the columns is empty (NA):

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | NA | 1 |
| y | NA | 4 | 4 |
| z | 2 | NA | 2 |
| p | NA | 5 | 5 |
| t | 6 | 7 | error |

In case both columns contain a value, it should return the text 'error' inside the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There as several ways to achieve this.

Using [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)

```
df['D'] = df['B'].fillna(df['C']).mask(df['B'].notna()&df['C'].notna(), 'error')
```

Or [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m1 = df['B'].notna()
m2 = df['C'].notna()
df['D'] = np.select([m1&m2, m1], ['error', df['B']], df['C'])
```

Output:

```
   A    B    C      D
0  x  1.0  NaN    1.0
1  y  NaN  4.0    4.0
2  z  2.0  NaN    2.0
3  p  NaN  5.0    5.0
4  t  6.0  7.0  error
```

Answer (score 2):

You could first calculate a mask with rows where both values are present and then fill `NA` values of, let's say column `B`, with values from column `C`. Using the mask calculated in the first step simply assign `NA` values where needed.

```
error_mask = df['B'].notna() & df['C'].notna()
df['D'] = df['B'].fillna(df['C'])
df.loc[error_mask, 'D'] = pd.NA
df

   A     B     C     D
0  x     1  <NA>     1
1  y  <NA>     4     4
2  z     2  <NA>     2
3  p     3     5  <NA>


OR
df = df['D'].astype(str)
df.loc[error_mask, 'D'] = 'error'
```

I would suggest against assigning a string `error` where both values are present, since that would make the whole `D` column an `object` dtype

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answer, you can address this with a series of `.apply()` methods paired with `lambda` functions.

Consider the dataframe that you presented, with `np.nan` as the NA values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'B':[1, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 6], 
    'C':[np.nan, 4, np.nan, 5, 7]})
```

First generate a list of the elements from the series in question:

```
df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x: list(x), axis=1)
```

This will net you a `pd.Series` with a list of values as elements, e.g. `[1.0, nan]` for the first row. Next, remove all `np.nan` elements by using that `np.nan != np.nan` in `numpy` (see also an answer here: [How can I remove Nan from list Python/NumPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011777/how-can-i-remove-nan-from-list-python-numpy))

```
df['E'] = df['D'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i == i])
```

Finally, create the `error` by filtering based on length.

```
df['F'] =  df['E'].apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) == 1 else 'error')
```

The resulting dataframe works like this:

```
    B   C   D   E   F
0   1.0 NaN [1.0, nan]  [1.0]   1.0
1   NaN 4.0 [nan, 4.0]  [4.0]   4.0
2   2.0 NaN [2.0, nan]  [2.0]   2.0
3   NaN 5.0 [nan, 5.0]  [5.0]   5.0
4   6.0 7.0 [6.0, 7.0]  [6.0, 7.0]  error
```

Of course you could chain all this together in a not-so-pythonic, yet single-line answer:
`a = df.apply(lambda x: list(x), axis=1).apply(lambda x: [i for i in x if i == i]).apply(lambda x: x[0] if len(x) == 1 else 'error')`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the function [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
df['C'].combine_first(df['B']).mask(df['B'].notna() & df['C'].notna(), 'error')
```

Output:

```
0      1.0
1      4.0
2      2.0
3      5.0
4    error
Name: C, dtype: object
```